# Error occured when opening Epub from PHP header EPUB file using Epub JS Library

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, epub, safe-publication

I'm trying to open Epub file from my own server.

PHP:

```
<?php
    $filename = '../files/2.epub';
    header('Content-type: application/epub+zip');
    header("Content-Disposition:inline;filename='somefilename.epub'");
    //header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    readfile($filename);
?>
```

Javascript:

```
 <script>
        var Book = ePub("http://localhost/epub/examples/file.php"); 
        Book.renderTo("area");
 </script>
```

ERROR occured:

```
Navigated to http://localhost/epub/examples/basic.html
core.js:120 GET http://localhost/epub/examples/file.phpMETA-      INF/container.xml 404 (Not Found)EPUBJS.core.request @     core.js:120EPUBJS.Book.loadXml @ book.js:586EPUBJS.Book.loadPackage @     book.js:188EPUBJS.Book.open @ book.js:148EPUBJS.Book @ book.js:115root.ePub @     base.js:48(anonymous function) @ basic.html:95
book.js:204 Could not load book at: META-INF/container.xml(anonymous func  tion) @ book.js:204lib$rsvp$$internal$$tryCatch @     rsvp.js:493lib$rsvp$$internal$$invokeCallback @     rsvp.js:505lib$rsvp$$internal$$publish @    rsvp.js:476lib$rsvp$$internal$$publishRejection @  rsvp.js:419lib$rsvp$asap$$flush @ rsvp.js:1198
book.js:1357 Object {message: null, stack: "Error↵    at XMLHttpRequest.handler (http://localhost/epub/build/epub.js:3493:13)"}
```

It works when I use the url directed to the file like this this:

```
var Book = ePub("http://localhost/epub/files/1.epub");
```

My goal is to view epub file but before that, I need to validate whether the user can view the epub.

I use this plugin for viewing. 
https://github.com/futurepress/epub.js

I'm using angularJS. In the future, I will be saving it in the indexedDB or Web SQL for local viewing.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you find the solution? facing the same issue

Comment: @nasirkhan see my provided answer.

Answer (score 0):

More a workaround than an actual solution. For some reason if the url does not end with .epub, epubjs does something different in the handling.

My original url is:

```
http://localhost/api.php?getbook=true&externalbookid=a13a9cef-1f83-4695-8cbf-1c0aafbf958e
```

In JS:

```
var book = ePub("http://localhost/file.epub?bookexternalid=5090a553-aa97-44a7-85cc-94ad07a6dc44");
```

I went with htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule file.epub/?$ /api.php?getbook=true&%{QUERY_STRING} [R=301,NC,L]
```

This should fix your problem.